# Connect java spring boot app to SAP event mesh (BTP)

Tags: spring-boot, sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-sdk

I'm currently trying to connect a java application (running on premise) to the SAP event mesh to receive messages published by some SAP system.

The colleagues provided a json file with credentials and endpoints:

```json
{
    "namespace": ":)",
    "xsappname": ":)",
    "management": [
        {
            "oa2": {
                "clientid": ":)",
                "clientsecret": ":)",
                "tokenendpoint": "https://whatever.authentication.eu20.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/token",
                "granttype": "client_credentials"
            },
            "uri": "https://em-hub-backend.cfapps.eu20.hana.ondemand.com"
        }
    ],
    "serviceinstanceid": ":)",
    "messaging": [
        {
            "oa2": {
                "clientid": ":)",
                "clientsecret": ":)",
                "tokenendpoint": "https://whatever.authentication.eu20.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/token",
                "granttype": "client_credentials"
            },
            "protocol": [
                "amqp10ws"
            ],
            "broker": {
                "type": "sapmgw"
            },
            "uri": "wss://em-messaging-gateway.cfapps.eu20.hana.ondemand.com/protocols/amqp10ws"
        },
        {
            "oa2": {
                "clientid": ":)",
                "clientsecret": ":)",
                "tokenendpoint": "https://whatever.authentication.eu20.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/token",
                "granttype": "client_credentials"
            },
            "protocol": [
                "mqtt311ws"
            ],
            "broker": {
                "type": "sapmgw"
            },
            "uri": "wss://em-messaging-gateway.cfapps.eu20.hana.ondemand.com/protocols/mqtt311ws"
        },
        {
            "oa2": {
                "clientid": ":)",
                "clientsecret": ":)",
                "tokenendpoint": "https://whatever.authentication.eu20.hana.ondemand.com/oauth/token",
                "granttype": "client_credentials"
            },
            "protocol": [
                "httprest"
            ],
            "broker": {
                "type": "saprestmgw"
            },
            "uri": "https://em-pubsub.cfapps.eu20.hana.ondemand.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

According to the SAP help page there are 3 supported protocols (https://help.sap.com/viewer/bf82e6b26456494cbdd197057c09979f/Cloud/en-US/3f424ff1ae3b4bc084c4f1ea0be96f54.html)

- Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP) 1.0 over WebSocket
- Message Queuing Telemetry Transport (MQTT) 3.1.1 over WebSocket
- REST APIs for Messaging

I guess REST APIs have very bad performance. So I'd go for AMQP or MQTT over WS.
It's a bit hard to find a java client library that supports either AMQP or MQTT and secure websockets and oauth authentication.

I already had a look at SAP cloud sdk. But the feature overview tells me that messaging is still in planned state which means it's not available yet.

Do you have any suggestions how I can make progress here?

Answer (score 1):

UPD: my colleagues have recommended the [XBEM library](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sap.cloud.servicesdk.xbem) being currently the best option for event consumption from SAP. The libraries by CAP and SDK are adding convenience on top of it. Check more [docs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/bf82e6b26456494cbdd197057c09979f/Cloud/en-US/3f424ff1ae3b4bc084c4f1ea0be96f54.html) here.

The [SAP Cloud SDK](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/) had experimental support for the Enterprise Event mesh for S/4HANA but it was discontinued in favor of implementation by [CAP](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/java/provisioning-api). They promised to release a library that can be used as a dependency to simplify events consumption for both Java and Node.js. It seems to be taking longer than promised, see the current status in the screenshot:
[image]

When the library is released the SDK plans to provide additional convenience with type-safe access to events. Currently, that's impossible as there's no generally available release.

You can still try out CAP's library if you have a single tenant App. For reference consult their [docs](https://cap.cloud.sap/docs/about/features#events--messaging)

If you'd like to have Enterprise Events mesh support in the SAP Cloud SDK, please, create a feature request [here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-sdk/issues).